# Error when I try to change Catalog Name

Tags: database, catalog, url-rewrite

When I try to Change the category name from **"Product Catalog"** to **"Products"** it gives me this error **"URL key for specified store already exists."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is an old bug of Magento 2.  For more information and bug fixes
>   follow the links  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6671
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9290
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

Answer (score 0):

It means that whatever you are using as a name it already was used before so it can not use that again. You can not have multiple equal names within your categories. 
There is a way how you can have /menu1/test and /menu2/test but that a storefront thing that you need to fix.

**Just for answering this question->** If you don't have that category anymore you can just go to your database -> `url_rewrite` table and delete the entry that has that URL in it.